# How to specify time range for a DXScheduler for wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I am using DevExpress Scheduler in my Wpf application. I would like know how can I limit/restrict the scheduler to only display range from 9:00-06:00 as (it is the working hours). I tried this:

```
schedulerControl1.LimitInterval = new DevExpress.XtraScheduler.TimeInterval(somedatetime1, somedatetime2);
```

This puts a range on date i.e:  from somedatetime1 to somedatetime2.

Is there any other way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

For `DayView` and `WorkWeekView` you can use [`DayView.WorkTime`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfSchedulerDayView_WorkTimetopic) property to set the time limit and [`DayView.ShowWorkTimeOnly`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfSchedulerDayView_ShowWorkTimeOnlytopic) property to show time limit. For other views there are no such properties.